# Simple SSRS Report

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, reporting-services

After some reading and posting, I am fairly sure that I want to use SSDS to analyze some data I have.  However, I could use some pointers to help me get going.

I have a simple SQL Server table:

```
* PKID (Int)
* ApplicationName (VarChar)
* MethodName (VarChar)
* TimeInMs (Integer)
* DateTime (DateTime)
```

This table records the length of time it took for various methods to run in various applications. This table could potentially have tens of thousands of rows.

I would like to set up the following report:

> Average length of time for a method to run (Total and per App) for the following periods of time: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,20,30,40,50,60,120,240,360

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: The meaning of the "following periods of time" part of your requirement is not clear. Do you mean you want to calculate averages, then further summarise these into ranges in your report? (e.g <1ms, 0-1ms, 1-2ms ... 120-240ms, 240-360ms, >360ms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a kick start with SSRS? I can help you with that. I actually wrote a beginner's series in my blog (in progress) http://dbalink.wordpress.com/2009/01/17/how-to-report-authoring-in-ssrs-2005-part-i-the-database/

I have worked extensively with data with time variables, blah, blah,...

Good thing is you can send me sample data. I might be able to help you build the whole thing from the ground up. :-)

Comment: mines a step-by-step guide to creating a basic drilldown report, without using the wizard.
http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/creating-a-basic-drilldown-report-in-ssr-2005

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what stage you're at so far (do you have SSRS installed?), it's hard to know how to answer...

Without being too facetious, there are lots of starter articles using the world's favourite search engine with these keywords: [reporting services tutorial](http://www.google.com/search?q=reporting+services+tutorial)

I'd particularly recommend [the Red Gate one](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/beginning-sql-server-2005-reporting-services-part-1/) (5th result in search)

Edit, after comment

Yes, create a table with your timings and use that JOINed to the main table to get the data to be displayed. Can you post some sample data and sample output please?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I do have SSRS installed. The thing I am trying to understand is how to get the results I am after for the whole range of timings I listed.  Do i need to put these in a table, then join against these, or I can I manually set against these (easily), or am I just missing the point entirely!